# Change Datatables options through jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

So, I have a table using the Datatables plugin. This table has a left fixed column to start with as well. Each one of my columns has a button to 'anchor' its column from scrolling, so fixing it in place.

You can change how many left columns you have fixed in the initialization with

```
new FixedColumns( oTable, {
        "iLeftColumns": 1
    } );
```

or `"iLeftColumns": 2` and so on.

I already have my programming set to push the column to the far left, so now i just need to overwrite the iLeftColumns accordingly. How would I go about overwriting the datatables initialization with jQuery, on the anchor button click? With one column anchor clicked, iLeftColumns would be 2, but maybe the user anchors another column and makes it 3 and so on.

Comment: Can you include more of your code? It will be easier to provide an answer that will work with what you have done so far.

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to re-initialize the datatable with a different parameter value after it has already been rendered.  This discussion might help you out: http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/1244/how-to-re-initialize-a-datatable-reload-it-from-scratch/p1